# Why git doesn't ask how to merge some of the files?

Tags: git, merge

I'm trying to merge two branches. Let's say that I have three files A, B and C.
In branch master I have three files A, B and C. And in branch 'new' I have A and C and I deleted B. Also C and A is different from C and A in 'master'.

Now I'm merging 'master' with 'new' and what git does is it replace 'master' version of C with 'new' version of C, it keeps B (which I actually want to delete) and it asks me to merge manually A. What is going on?
I thought that it would ask me about all changes!

BUT! If I compare two branches it shows all the differences correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Git is working as you say you want it to work.

Let's say I have `A` `B` and `C` files with each their content. You can test the behaviour following these commands:

```
git init
git add A B C
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

then create the branch

```
git checkout -b branch1
<edit A, edit C>
git rm B
git add A C
git commit -m "branch commit 1"
```

then perform the merge from branch1 to master

```
git checkout master
git merge branch1
```

In this case, git will fast-forward your changes  :

```
Fast-forward
 A | 4 ++--
 B | 5 -----
 C | 6 +++---
 3 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 10 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 B
```

Conflict will appear if you made changes both in `master` and `branch1`.

---

Expanded case from comment :

You have file `A` containing `AAAAAA` on the first line, `B` with `BBBBBBB` and `C` with `CCCCCC`.

```
git init
git add A B C
git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

Branching to `branch1`

```
git checkout -b branch1
```

Replace the first line of  `A` with `DDDDD` 
Add `DDDDD` to the second line of `C`

```
git rm B
git add A C
git commit -m "branch commit 1"
```

Back to `master`

```
git checkout master
```

Replace the first line of  `A` with `EEEEEE` (thus preparing a conflict)
Add a `CCCCC` line to `B`

```
git add A B
git commit -m "master commit 1"
```

Now we perform the merge

git merge branch1

```
CONFLICT (modify/delete): B deleted in branch1 and modified in HEAD. Version HEAD of B left in tree.
Auto-merging A
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in A
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

`B` is still there.
So basically now you have to decide what to do now

```
git add B # Keeping B
git rm B  # Trashing B
```

You need to solve `A` conflict by editing it. Then

```
git add A
```

to stage it for commit.

If you `git status` you will see that `C` has been modified (porting the changes you made in `branch1` as it is intended with revision control!) but you have the opportunity to revert the file to the master version using :

```
git checkout HEAD C
```

This behaviour can be done for other merge when the is no conflict, but you have to force a manual commit with `git merge --no-commit <branch>`

Comment: Yeah... My first question to you then is why in my case it doesn't removed B in merge? And second question is how do I keep 'master' version of 'C'?

Comment: Expanded use case has been added. Hope it helps.

Comment: Well, it kind of helps. But what if I don't want to manually remove B (and in reality it's a lot of files) And I can't create conflict because in 'new' version of A there is no line in common at all. I just removed anything from file and started from scratch.

Comment: To be honest, I do not see any solution to prefer branch modifications (removal of B) and prefer master versions (modifications of C) in a non interactive mode. Regarding `A`, if you cleaned the lines in `master` and changed it in `branch1`, it will generate a conflict. Maybe in your case you would benefit better from a `cherry-pick` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an answer, but I can't comment you question...I will edit this post regarding your answer

You should provide the result of the command: `git status`

I assume you are in the middle of the merge, so you have to resolve conflicts (choose if you want to keep B and manually merge A)

Comment: On branch new_graph_lib
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/new_graph_lib'.
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

 new file:   .idea/dictionaries/michael.xml
 new file:   .idea/scopes/scope_settings.xml

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 .idea/workspace.xml